# Matlab - normalized rgb color space

Tags: matlab

So I have an image img.jpg I read the image with

```
Im = imread('img.jpg');
I = im2double(Im);
```

I got separate channels from it

```
R = I(:,:,1);
G = I(:,:,2);
B = I(:,:,3);
```

I calculated the sum like this

```
S = R+G+B;
```

Now when I divide the blue channel with S

```
NV = B/S;
B = NV;
```

I get a weird image back with

```
imshow(B);
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if S is a matrix, you need to use element-wise division:

```
NV = B/S;
```

should be

```
NV = B./S;
```

Comment: it is a matlab notation to make an operation element-wise instead of matrix operation

Comment: @StevenSeagull if the answer is correct, could you mark as best answer? thanks